# Node js - Importing mssql module for use in an Angular 2 project errors : " Can't resolve 'dns' " and " Can't resolve 'dgram' "

Tags: sql-server, node.js, angular, debugging, dependency-injection

I have rudimentary experience in both Angular 2 and NodeJS development. I apologize if this question is too simple of nature.

My goal is to create a web interface which connects to a SQL Server database. This app would enable the user to easily send queries to and receive results from the connected database from the app.

Searching for solutions, I decided to import [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) module into my `mssql-connection.service.ts` after installing via npm. I was planning to use it in the service either by using dependency injection or its regular syntax. However,  I am experiencing error while compiling in each of those situations.

First, in trying to use the DI method by writing `import { MSSQL } from 'mssql';` I get two duplicate error messages `node_modules/@types/mssql/index"' has no exported member 'MSSQL'.`

Second, in my attempt to remedy the situation as a response, I write `import 'mssql';`. Then I get a total of three error messages: I get two duplicate error messages `Can't resolve 'dns' in '...\node_modules\tedious\lib'` and an error message `Can't resolve 'dgram' in '...\node_modules\tedious\lib'` I have also tried using `const sql = require('mssql');` but this would give me `Cannot find name 'require'.` error message, preceded by the previous error messages.

I am stumped and would like to know why this is happening! I would like to be able to use external modules freely. I have also tried `npm install @types/mssql` but to no avail. My node version is v6.9.5, and am using Angular 4.0.0. Please help!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you share some code on what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really think what you're trying to achieve here is makes any sense. Don't you think it would be an anti-pattern to use this in your Angular App? How exactly are you supposed to distribute this App and make it secure as well?

I would suggest you use mssql, in your NodeJS project. You can expose APIs from there that you'll hit from your Angular App. That's what is the purpose of a client after all.

Doing this will make your code more manageable, maintainable, and loosely coupled.

Hope this makes sense.